# SFDX: custom fields not displaying in force:source:status after undelete

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, undelete

I created a custom object and then a custom field. Then I deleted the field and undeleted it respectively. Now when I run `sfdx force:source:status` that custom field is not displayed.

If I create another custom field it gets displayed but not the undeleted one. Do  you know how to get the undeleted field to display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that after undeleting the fields they looked like `Custom_Field_del__c` and I suppose that's why `force:source:status` was not picking them up. After getting rid of the `_del` part the fields got picked up again.

**TL;DR** I switched the field name from `Custom_Field_del__c` back to `Custom_Field__c` and that fixed it.